# How to install pyarrow in Amazon Linux 2 m6g instance

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-ec2, pyarrow

I'm trying to install pyarrow in Amazon Linux 2 m6g instance which have ARM architecture. I have installed several dependencies and now I'm stuck on this error when I run `pip3.8 install pyarrow`:

```
-- Found the Arrow core static library: /usr/lib64/libarrow.a
    -- Could NOT find ArrowPython (missing: ArrowPython_DIR)
    -- Checking for module 'arrow-python'
    --   No package 'arrow-python' found
    CMake Error at /usr/local/share/cmake-3.18/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:165 (message):
      Could NOT find ArrowPython (missing: ARROW_PYTHON_INCLUDE_DIR
      ARROW_PYTHON_LIB_DIR) (found version "2.0.0")
    Call Stack (most recent call first):
      /usr/local/share/cmake-3.18/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:458 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
      cmake_modules/FindArrowPython.cmake:76 (find_package_handle_standard_args)
      CMakeLists.txt:215 (find_package)
```

It says that I need to install the package ArrowPython. When I run `sudo yum install arrow-python-libs` to install this package I get this error:

```
Error: Package: openblas-threads-0.3.3-2.el7.aarch64 (epel)
           Requires: libgfortran.so.3()(64bit)
Error: Package: openblas-threads-0.3.3-2.el7.aarch64 (epel)
           Requires: libgfortran.so.3(GFORTRAN_1.0)(64bit)
Error: Package: openblas-serial-0.3.3-2.el7.aarch64 (epel)
           Requires: libgfortran.so.3(GFORTRAN_1.0)(64bit)
Error: Package: python36-numpy-1.12.1-1.el7.aarch64 (epel)
           Requires: libpython3.6m.so.1.0()(64bit)
Error: Package: python36-numpy-1.12.1-1.el7.aarch64 (epel)
........
Error: Package: openblas-serial-0.3.3-2.el7.aarch64 (epel)
           Requires: libgfortran.so.3()(64bit)
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

I have tried also with other pyarrow versions but I'm getting the same error.

How can I solve this?

Comment: One approach would be to use `conda` as the source for your packages. There we have `pyarrow` built for `aarch64`. Alternatively, we are in the progress of building wheels for `aarch64`. Best is to either look at the respective PR on github or open an issue in the Arrow JIRA.

Comment: Thanks, I have found this PR https://github.com/apache/arrow/pull/8491. Meanwhile, I will use conda.

Comment: I'm the engineer who posted that PR. I haven't worked on it in a while, but when I do, I'll post an update here.

Comment: @JonathanSwinney how is going the PR?

Comment: I've been distracted by other things and it looks like I'm going to rebase and retest. It might be helpful if you would comment on the PR indicating that you need support for aarch64 wheels.

Comment: PR commented @JonathanSwinney

Comment: @Shadowtrooper pyarrow 4.0 has been released now with aarch64 support!

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't install via conda. Or the conda one had Import errors when I try `import pyarrow`. But got it working. With conda installed, via:

`pip install pyarrow=2`